# How to keep only last 3 digits of an integer and be able to manipulate them?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that would ask a user to enter an integer, keep only the last 3 digits of that input, and be able to manipulate that. For example, if they entered 1234, it would keep only 234 then it would be able to reverse those digits and output 432. Then I would want to be able to perform arithmetic on that reversed number. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Convert to `String`, pull out the `subString()`, reverse, convert back to `int`?

Comment: Please include code from your current attempt

Comment: What should be output for `4012`?  Do you require the string `"012"` or the number `12`.  (And is the reversed result `21` or `"210"` ?)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `%` (remainder) operator and then a `StringBuilder`

```
int val = 1234;
val = val % 1000;

System.out.println(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(val)).reverse());
```

Answer (score -1):

Check I think it mayhelp you.

```
 String input = "1234";     //input string
 String lastFourDigits = "";     //substring containing last 3 characters
 int reversed = 0;

 if (input.length() > 3) {
    lastFourDigits = input.substring(input.length() - 3);
 } else {
    lastFourDigits = input;
 }
 Number num = Integer.parseInt(lastFourDigits);

 while(num != 0) {
        int digit = num % 10;
        reversed = reversed * 10 + digit;
        num /= 10;
 }

System.out.println("last 3 Number: " + lastFourDigits);
System.out.println("Reversed Number: " + reversed);
```